# The database data is not updated in the application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Please help. When changing the database version in the code, nothing comes - the data in the application remains from the old database.

Where is the problem?
I make changes to the database. I change the database version number, but nothing changes in the application.

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; 
    private static String DB_NAME = "bd.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 28; //version
    static final String TABLE = "categories_second";
    private Context myContext;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE+"(_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,name TEXT NOT NULL,items TEXT,categories INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,pictures TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
            onCreate(db);            
    }

    void create_db() {
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

                String outFileName = DB_PATH;
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to happen, exactly, but I would point out that you never call `create_db()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use DatabaseHelper?

I have a similar setup as you - without `create_db`.

When I change the version in Helper, I also need to change version when I am calling the helper

```
dbHandler = new ButtonDBHandler(this, null, null, 2);
```